# Coroutine versus object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, coroutine

Why use a coroutine which is a function maintaining an internal state between calls instead of an object which also has an internal state?

Comment: Can you give some examples?

Comment: Because it's easier to resume execution with a coroutine (and they're easier to write since the system mostly takes care of maintaining state for you.

Comment: While it doesn't address your question directly, I think that this youtube video of a PyCon lecture by David Beazley titled [_Curious Course on Coroutines and Concurrency_](https://youtu.be/Z_OAlIhXziw) would help you understand what coroutines are capable of (and implicitly how doing the same thing with a class instance object would be very difficult if not impossible).

Comment: @martineau It is never impossible. In fact it is always possible. It just is harder and more brittle. It is better to leave the transform to the compiler.

Comment: @DanD.: It can be impossible for practical reasons, such as requiring too much memory, taking too long, requiring access to the "state" of external things you don't have, etc—or otherwise simply be too difficult to be feasible.

Comment: @martineau I prefer the term infeasible for that. And reserve the term impossible for the uncomputable. Any program in direct style with control operators can be converted by automatic means to a program in inverted style without control operators. Letting the compiler do this for you is so much easier than doing it manually.

Answer (score 2):

The rationale is pretty dramatic if you're used to Java's `Iterator` interface.

Consider this:

```
def my_generator():
    yield "first"
    yield "second"
    yield from some_list()
```

To write that as a class:

```
class MyIterator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.place = 0

    def __next__(self):
        if self.place == 0:
            result = "first"
            self.place += 1
        elif self.place == 1:
            result = "second"
            self.place += 1
            self.list_iter = iter(some_list())
        else:
            result = next(self.list_iter)  # Throws implicitly
        return result
```

Updating your state is just boilerplate, and if you can get the compiler / interpreter to write your boilerplate for you, why not?

Comment: Did you mean `yield from some_list()`, without the square brackets?

Comment: Good catch, fixed.